# Need help to modify API to pass order details (items and quantities) in WP

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I have hired a developper from FreeLancer to connect my WooCommerce to a delivery company system where the order details are passed to their system. API docs can be found in https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/9524868/T1LMi7ba?version=latest

I have tested everything but forgot to test the order details (item name and quantities) and paid the developer, as usual with a lot of free lancers, they won't even reply to you after getting the money. Now I need some help in finding the issue as I don't have much experience in this.

All the details are getting passed to their system successfully except for the items details (name and quantity). They show as empty fields.

Below is what the delivery company need for the order details:

```
{ "data": { "qty": 1, "name": "recheese black" } }
```

And this is what the developer made to fetch the info:

```
    // Pickup meta data
$order_products = array();
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $item_name   = $item->get_name();
    $item_quantity  = $item->get_quantity();
    $order_products[] = array('qty' => $item_quantity, 'name' => $item_name);
}

$pickup_meta_data_arr = array('data' => $order_products);
$pickup_meta_data = json_encode($pickup_meta_data_arr);
```

can someone spot what is wrong here?

In case someone needs this info, this is how the details are passed:

```
    $post_fields = array(
    'job_description' => $job_description, // ++
    'job_pickup_phone' => $snoonu_api_settings['phone'], // ++
    'job_pickup_name' => $snoonu_api_settings['name'], // ++
    'job_pickup_email' => $snoonu_api_settings['email'], // ++
    'job_pickup_address' => $snoonu_api_settings['address'], // ++
    'job_pickup_latitude' => $snoonu_api_settings['latitude'], // ++
    'job_pickup_longitude' => $snoonu_api_settings['longitude'], // ++
    'job_pickup_datetime' => $job_pickup_datetime, // ++
    'job_delivery_address' => $job_delivery_address, // ++
    'job_delivery_latitude' => $shipping_lat, // ++
    'job_delivery_longitude' => $shipping_long, // ++
    'job_delivery_phone' => $job_delivery_phone, // ++
    'job_delivery_name' => $job_delivery_name, // ++
    'job_delivery_email' => $job_delivery_email, // ++
    'job_delivery_datetime' => $job_delivery_datetime,
    'layout_type' => $layout_type, // ++
    'pickup_meta_data' => $pickup_meta_data, // ++
    'payment_method' => $payment_method, // ++
    'total' => $total, // ++
    'delivery_fee' => $delivery_fee, // ++
    'grand_total' => $grand_total, // ++
);
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? based on this code you will get order detail in the `pickup_meta_data` key.

Comment: The details are not getting passed to their system and show empty fields. 
Thank you for pointing it out, I made the issue clear in the main post.

Comment: But as per your given link, I can see `pickup_meta_data` have values.

Comment: Does it matter if there is specific format required by their system?

Comment: As you mentioned delivery company gives you the format and you are passing correctly.

Comment: What response do you get when you send this detail?